# How to get the Sansa Clip Plus memory card to be treated as just part of the existing 8GB hard drive by Banshee?

Tags: banshee

I recently purchased a Sansa Clip+ with 8 GB of storage.  That was not enough so I bought a 128GB microSDXC UHS-I Card with adapter.  When I boot up Banshee, the card is looked at as a separate device on which to store music and podcasts.  Is there a way to get Banshee to treat it as 128+8 = 136 GB of total storage rather than as a separate device?  Here is my ".is_audio_player" configuration file (which needs to be on both the 128GB and 8GB storage devices in order to be recognized by Banshee I believe) in case that helps.

```
audio_folders=Music/,Podcasts/
folder_depth=2
output_formats=audio/mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. The two storage locations are exposed as separate devices over the USB, so they will be displayed as such. There is no feature in Banshee, or udev, to have them combined into a single device.

Answer (score -1):

> Do you pine for the nice days of minix-1.1, when men were men and wrote their own device drivers?
>   - Linus Torvalds

If the device reports the SD card as a second device, then udev registers two separate device files.

If you think of yourself as a person who could do it, you could try to create your own driver which takes care of deciding where to put the files, but I can't think of anything else you could do about it.

Actually it makes more sense to display both storage devices separately, so you can control what goes where.